# vbscript- explorer process restored automatically after kill

Tags: vbscript, process, kill, wsh

I've used the below script a couple of times to kill processes in a vbscript without any issues.

This time I'm trying to kill explorer.exe. Only issue is after I use the script to kill explorer.exe within 2 seconds explorer process restores.

I don't understand ? because if I manually kill explorer.exe with Task Manager, the process is killed until I start the process again. So whats the issue with the below script?

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strProcessKill 
strComputer = "."
strProcessKill = "'explorer.exe'" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill )
For Each objProcess in colProcess
objProcess.Terminate()
Next 

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2):

A way :

```
Set oCMD = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oCMD.Run "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe",0,True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strProcessKill 
strComputer = "."
strProcessKill = "'explorer.exe'" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill )
For Each objProcess in colProcess
    objProcess.Terminate(1)
Next
```

Or like this way :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Process
Process = "Explorer.exe"
Call Kill(Process)
'****************************************************
Sub Kill(Process)
    Dim Ws,Command,Execution
    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "& Process &""
    Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
    Set Ws = Nothing
End Sub 
'****************************************************
```